# I want to fetch data real time data from MySQL in react native using socket

Tags: mysql, reactjs, react-native, websocket, socket.io

Can someone help me, I want to fetch real time data from MySQL database in react native through socket.
I know these days firebase works very well but it’s really so costly so need help using socket fetch real time data from MySQL database

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this. You can connect to WebSocket using stompjs or type socket(https://github.com/mat-sz/typesocket). if you are using redux-saga it is even easier.